# customer available ask for login?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am using below mention code for if already have account it ask to login else it display not available

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function emailcheck(email){
document.getElementById("myform").submit();
}

</script>

<?php 
  $email=$_POST['email'];

        if($_POST['email']){
       $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
        $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
        $customer->loadByEmail($email);
        if ($customer->getId()) {
        echo "available"; ?>  


         <div class="col-2">

        <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
        <form id="login-form" action="<?php echo $this->getPostAction() ?>" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
                       <ul class="form-list">
                <li>
                    <label for="login-email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" id="login-email" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="login-password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="password" class="input-text required-entry" id="login-password" name="login[password]" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
            </ul>
            <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
        </fieldset>
        </form>
        <div class="buttons-set">
            <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
           <div class="login-pass">
            <button type="submit" class="button" onclick="onepageLogin(this)"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
             <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/forgotpassword') ?>" class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot your password?') ?></a>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php    
        }
        else{
            echo"not available"; 
        }

}

?>
        <form id="myform" name ="myform" method="POST">
                <input placeholder="Email Address" type="email" name="email" id= "email" class="input-text " required />   

                <button class="button" name="submit" onclick="emailcheck();"/> <span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span> </button>
        </form>
```

But my problem is after login for is displayed but it's not logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use isset for getting the post data.

**remove this**

```
 $email=$_POST['email'];



change
if($_POST['email']){
```

to

```
 if(isset($_POST['email']) && !is_null($_POST['email'])){
```

Comment: No after that if condition it's not working

Answer (score 2):

If I remember, magento track the current user and you no need to write the code for it. Its login functionality works properly. You can restore login functionality from fresh magento installation. it should work

Comment: sorry i can't understand